# How we implement Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) without using Third Party SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have used this code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in `AppDelegate.m`,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability];
```

Comment: might be this will clear your doubts about push notifications..  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/

Comment: You beat me to it - that is *the* article to follow if you want to understand Push Notifications, both client side and server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to either rent or own a server that is responsible for communicating with Apple's APNS servers. Yes, when pushing notifications to your app's users, your server has to first push it to Apple and have Apple transfer those notifications to specific users on your behalf.

And second, override and implement the following methods in your AppDelegate's .m file:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {  
    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {  
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //You probably already implemented this one
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

And test your code and your server with Apple's Sandbox server before you put your app into production.

you can check the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) for more info